# Python Library To Calculate Porfolio Statistics

Tags: backtesting, portfolio, python, library

I am working through some backtesting ideas and I would love to capture the basic statistics results for comparison, (cumulative returns, annual returns, sharpe, omega etc.) 
Is there a python library that provides the calculation of the stats as callable functions similar to the ta-lib library, [Python's TA-Lib port](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Quantopian's empyrical package handles this exact use case [Quantopian Empyrical Package](https://github.com/quantopian/empyrical)

Comment: If this solves your problem, then you can accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved.